# Regular expression: Numeric + alphanum + special characters Only

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression that can find patterns that **MUST** contain both numeric and alphanumeric values along side special characters.
I found an answer that deals with this type of regular expressions but without the special characters.

How can I include the special characters including: **^$=()_"'[\@** in the Regular expression?

```
^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

can you explain it a little please ?

Regex tester : http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Thank you.

AS a solution I found this regular expression: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{4,8}$`

Maybe it can help you.

Comment: define `special characters`

Comment: If by special characters, you mean the non-word characters (Word Chars are letter, number and underscore) you can use the `\W` flag in your expression.

Comment: Special characters: **-,_;/\[]#@**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complicated !?

```
enum { numeric = 1; alpha = 2, special = 4; }

bool check(const std::string& s) {
   for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size; ++i) {
      if(is_numeric(s[i])) result |= numeric;
      if(is_alpha(s[i])) result |= alpha;
      if(is_special(s[i])) result |= special;
      if(result == numeric | alpha | special) 
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

A little more typing but less brain damage

Comment: Yes well it is brain damage actually. I'll be doing it the hardcore way the next time.

Thank you @Dieter I'll use this code it's much easier

Comment: This is very readable, but unfortunately very slow compared to the regex solution (with a proper regex engine of course).

Comment: You might be able to optimize this by using a `contains` type method, rather than explicitly looping over the string. While each `contains` might loop in itself, they will likely have some optimizations and early-out, which will save you a fair amount of time in good cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is formed of two parts, both must capture a complete line as they're between start-of-line (`^`) and end-of-line (`$`):

1. ([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)
   This is formed of two regexs or'd (`|`) together. The first regex is one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) followed by one or more letters (`[a-zA-Z]+`).  This regex is or'd with the opposite case regex: one or more letters followed by one or more numbers.
2. The second group says that the above is followed by a regex zero or more letters or numbers (`[0-9a-zA-Z]*`)

Comment: Oh ok now it's much better, So If I have to include the special characters, It has to be at the
**1. Beginning**
**2. Between the 2 groups**
**3. the end**